# Jquery not retaining class after post back

Tags: jquery

I am displaying some content using XSL(XML) 1.0. I have acategory and a subcategory; when I hit link in category it adds a query parameter. I was trying to add/remove a class using jQuery on click of link . It gets changed but after page refresh it removes any changes.

```
Category
---------
United States
Australia
India

SubCategory
--------------
United States
Texas
New York
Florida

Australia
Sydney
Melbourne
Brisbane

India

Delhi
Mumbai
Gujrat
```

So when I click United States, it adds `?Category=United States` and I want to display subcategory only for United States:

```
$('.main-nav ul li').click(function(){
        $('.main-nav ul li').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            var contentId = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(contentId);

                changeContent();
});

function changeContent(){   
            $('.sub-nav').removeClass('currentitem');
            //find which item is current
            var contentId = $('.main-nav ul li.current').attr("id");
            //display the related content
            $("div#" + contentId).addClass('currentitem');

    }
```

and I was hiding and showing content throw CSS. So it changes the class when I click but as the query-parameter refreshes the page , it removes everything.

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to click the link without refreshing the page, or to display the reloaded page with the class applied to the selected content?

Comment: Second one, reloaded page with class applied to the selected content.

Comment: It was simple, I managed to do all this change class at page load instead of page click by checking query string..